# Is there any way to add scroll bar in 'markdown' cell to shorten jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I'm collecting the output result, and want to save it to a table(markdown). However, the table is too long, so it takes too much space, and it's hard for me to scroll to see the whole table. So is it possible to add a scroll bar in markdown cell? Or any other suggestion?

I've tried jupyter notebook Nbextensions but found no relative extension.